# In the Django admin page for a given model, is it possible to create one or more models that have the original given model as a foreign key field?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

For example, let's say we have Cars and Manufacturers, where the Cars model contains a foreign key to Manufacturers (many cars to one manufacturer). In the Manufacturer admin page, when you are creating a new Manufacturer, you get to input whatever fields a manufacturer might have, such as name or address for example.

Is there a way to also be able to create a new Car belonging to the given Manufacturer on the Manufacturer admin page? For instance, you would be prompted to select a Car on the Manufacturer page, or have the ability to create one if the one you want does not exist. If this is possible, is there a way to create an arbitrary amount of cars that belong to this manufacturer this way?

Comment: You are looking for [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

Comment: The docs don't seem to mention this, but do you know in what file these should be in? Models.py?

Comment: Or should the inline and admin class be in admin.py?

Comment: They should be in `admin.py`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your car has foreign key to manufacturer, you should be able to choose in Django Admin

in your models:

```
from django.db import models

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
     name = models.CharacterField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
     location = models.CharacterField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)         

     class Meta:
         verbose_name = 'Manufacturer'
         verbose_name_plural = 'Manufacturers'

     def __str__(self):
           return name



class Car(models.Model):
     manufacturer= models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer,null=True)
     model = models.CharacterField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)

    class Meta:
         verbose_name = 'Car'
         verbose_name_plural = 'Cars'         

    def __str__(self):
         return model
```

In your admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Manufacturer
from models import Car


class ManufacturerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = ((None, {'fields': ['name','location']}),)

    class Meta:
         verbose_name = 'Manufacturer'
         verbose_name_plural = 'Manufacturers'



class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = ((None, {'fields': ['manufacturer','model']}),)

    class Meta:
         verbose_name = 'Car'
         verbose_name_plural = 'Cars


 admin.site.register(Manufacturer,ManufacturerAdmin)
 admin.site.register(Car,CarAdmin)
```

This should do it.

Comment: Doesn't this just show fields that are shown by default anyways? I was looking for a way to basically add a 'Car' field to the Manufacturer admin page.